# Parse each number from a string and store in a new column in R

Tags: r, split

The below is currently a sample row in a dataframe I have in R and I'm looking for a way to split out each of the 12 numbers in its own column.

```
    Pos. Part.: 16       , 18       , 28       , 37       , 64       , 67     Neg. Part.: 11       , 28       , 34       , 41       , 55       , 72
```

What are the best string manipulation functions for accomplishing this? Thanks!

Comment: `str_extract_all` works for my purposes, thanks. I don't have any use for the text parts like `Pos. Part.:`.

Comment: It might be worth taking a step back. Are all of the rows in the same format? There are read functions that can handle structured data without needing to post-process. What is the source of the data? A file?

Comment: Given that this is a row in a larger object, I suggest it might be beneficial (as @David_O suggested) to see more context. While we may be able to brute-force an answer for what you ask for, it might not be the best answer for what you need.

Comment: @David_O All of the rows are in the same format, although the number of numbers separated by commas can vary. I'm using `rvest` to scrape hockey box scores, which is the source of the data, for example this one: [link](http://stats.swehockey.se/Game/Events/441966)

Comment: Ah. That's tough. That column in the table has all sorts of formatted text, so you are going to have to deal with the different kinds on a case by case basis. Regular expressions are going to be your friend here (`?regexpr`) - if you haven't used them before the syntax is a little tricky but they are invaluable (and they are what the answer below @chris uses (that `\\d' is a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Chris's answer extracts the numbers neatly, but I suspect the problem for you is that it merges Pos and Neg and you can't then separate them. If you always get both Pos and Neg you can use a regexpr that grabs those two groups. However, if you can just get one or the other, then you won't know which was found with a single match.

So, the most robust approach is to search for Pos and Neg separately. The code below uses a `regexpr` trick called a lookbehind. It matches text that is preceded by another pattern, but the other pattern isn't included in the match. We're just after the numbers (a mix of spaces commas and 0-9). So given:

```r
ch <- 'Pos. Part.: 16       , 18       , 28       , 37       , 64       , 67     Neg. Part.: 11       , 28       , 34       , 41       , 55       , 72'
```

We can use it to get to `16       , 18       , 28       , 37       , 64       , 67` and `11       , 28       , 34       , 41       , 55       , 72` and then can get the numbers.

```r
pos <- regexpr('(?<=Pos. Part.:)[ ,0-9]+', ch, perl=TRUE)
neg <- regexpr('(?<=Neg. Part.:)[ ,0-9]+', ch, perl=TRUE)
```

Now we can extract those matches and get back to the numbers.

```r
pos <- regmatches(pos, ch)
neg <- regmatches(neg, ch)
pos <- strsplit
```

We can now use @Chris's pattern to extract the numbers, but can also just use `strsplit`. Using `pos` as an example:

```r
pos <- strsplit(pos, ',')[[1]]
# That leaves spaces all over the place, so:
pos <- trimws(pos)
[1] "16" "18" "28" "37" "64" "67"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're after just the numbers, this should work:

```
#data:
hockey <- c("Pos. Part.: 16       , 18       , 28       , 37       , 64       , 67     Neg. Part.: 11")

# define pattern to be matched:
pattern <- "\\d{2}"

# define function to extract raw matches:
extract <- function(x) unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x, perl = T)))

# extract raw matches:
extract(hockey)
extract
[1] "16" "18" "28" "37" "64" "67" "11"
```

If the numbers can vary in terms of number of numeric characters they contain, adapt the `pattern` thus:

```
pattern <- "\\d{1,}" # matches numbers with at least one numeric character
```